# Smarty conditional inside a tag

Tags: php, html, smarty

I want to create an attribute in a an  just if a condition applies. Say I have a condition in a var like this: $mycondition.

I am trying to do:

```
<a {if $mycondition} attribute = "test" {{/if}} href="...">link</a>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Simple PHP isn't enough for this?

Comment: I just can't put the smarty conditinoal code inside the "a" element

Comment: Not working: `{{/if}}` change to `{/if}`

Comment: I wouldn't embed a conditional inside of a tag... Makes your code harder to read. I would just do if/else with two completely different anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove double brackets in the end of `if` condition. Also, don't leave spaces between attribute and it's value. This should work for you:

```
<a {if $mycondition}attribute="test"{/if} href="...">link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the smarty assign function. [Here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl) is a link to the documentation. You can do something like

```
 <{if $mycondition}><{assign var="attribute" value="test"}<{/if}>
```

You can then use attribute like `<{$attribute}>` in your code. Will that work?

Comment: Maybe I read to far into it, if you're just trying to add an attribute like `disabled`, you can do that within the link, like `<a href="..."<{if $condition}> disabled<{/if}>>Link text</a>`